# Unicode confusion #3423435

Tags: unicode, python-2.x, python-unicode

Once again I enter that goddamn unicode-hell ... sigh =(

There are two files:

```
$ file *
kreise_tmp.geojson:        ASCII text
pandas_tmp.csv:            UTF-8 Unicode text
```

I read the first file like this:

```
with open('kreise_tmp.geojson') as f:
 jdata = json.loads(f.read())
```

I read the second file like this:

```
pandas_data = pd.read_csv(r'pandas_tmp.csv', sep=";")
```

Now check out what's inside the strings:

```
>>> jdata['features'][0]['properties']['name']
u'Kreis Euskirchen' # a unicode string?

>>> pandas_data['kreis'][0]
'Kreis D\xc3\xbcren' # not a unicode string?
```

Why are the strings from the "UTF-8 Unicode text" file just normal strings and the strings from the "ASCII text" file unicode strings?

Comment: Please attach `hexdump` of  `kreise_tmp.geojson` and `pandas_tmp.csv`. Also note that by specification json format can't contain non asci symbols. So json probably contains same `\xc3` but it loads into `ü`. I guess you need to specify encoding - utf8 while opening file, check if `pd.read_csv` contains encoding param, if it doesn't you need to manually convert `bytes` to utf8.

Comment: What version of Python? Try upgrading to Python 3.6.

Comment: @deathangel908 JSON can contain non-ASCII symbols just fine. http://json.org/ - "*Any UNICODE character* ..."

Comment: I would try specifying `encoding='utf-8'` in `read_csv()`. I never used pandas but chances are good it decodes the bytestrings to unicode if you tell it the encoding to use.

Comment: Each text file (including JSON) is encoded with the encoding it was written with. You must read it with that encoding. The current contents of a particular sample text file might be valid to be decoded with many of the hundreds of encodings.  `file` will give you one among possibilities that it knows about. If you want to know if the current contents of a text file is valid to be decoded with a particular encoding, you just have to read it with that encoding. JSON, though, uses one of three easily distinguished encodings, given the required JSON syntax. Otherwise, it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @deathangel908 "*note that by specification json format can't contain non asci symbols*" - that is completely wrong. [Read the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) more carefully: "*JSON text is a sequence of Unicode code points... A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022). All characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark (U+0022), reverse solidus (U+005C), and the control characters U+0000 to U+001F.*"

Comment: @deathangel908: so, ANY Unicode codepoint other then those 34 reserved codepoints can appear as-is in JSON (the 34 have to be encoded in `\u` format in strings).  So, when parsing a file, or (whatever), you just have to take its charset encoding into account. The JSON could be encoded in any Unicode-compatible charset, like ASCII (if only ASCII characters are used) or UTF-8.

Comment: @TomBlodget: JSON itself doesn't define any particular encoding (except for the `\u` encoded format in strings), its grammar is simply defined in terms of Unicode codepoints (like XML is). The user of the JSON decides what encoding to use in memory, file, transmissions, etc, as long as it is compatible with the data that is being used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes the [EMCA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) standard does not but [RFC 7159](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159) says, "JSON text SHALL be encoded in UTF-8, UTF-16, or UTF-32." So, as a matter of practice, a writer should use one of those and a reader should use whatever it is told to.

Answer (score 2):

JSON strings are always Unicode.

```
~$ python2
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('"\xc3\xbc"')
u'\xfc'
```

But they are often serialized with `\u` escapes, so `file` will only see ASCII.

```
>>> json.dumps(_)
'"\\u00fc"'
```

Answer (score 0):

add `encoding='utf-8'` to the opening of files to decode them with utf-8

```
pandas_data = pd.read_csv(r'pandas_tmp.csv', sep=";",  encoding='utf8')
```

you can also do the same with the JSON

```
with open('kreise_tmp.geojson',  encoding='utf8') as f:
    jdata = json.loads(f.read())
```

Also in Python 2.7, you can add this to the top of the file..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: That last bit just declares the encoding of the *source file*.  It has zero effect on JSON or pandas.  It affects string constants in the source.